# How many monitors iMac 21.5 4K can handle?

Tags: display, imac, thunderbolt, hdmi

Well, Im a programmer and I want bunch of monitors.

I have a 21.5 Inch 5K iMac, from 2017

[image]

Just bought a [DUAL HDMI Adapter from StarTech.com](https://www.startech.com/AV/display-and-video-adapters/thunderbolt-3-video-adapters/thunderbolt-3-to-dual-hdmi~TB32HD24K60)

My intention is to have 3 extra displays because the Mac has 2 thunderbolt 3 ports so in 1 port I connected the StarTech adapter and in the other one a simple [Thunderbolt 3 to HDMI adapter](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MUF82AM/A/usb-c-digital-av-multiport-adapter?fnode=8b)

But when they are connected together I have 2 random displays working, I cant get the 3 extra display to work!

In the past I have both thunderbolt ports with the single HDMI adapter and worked fine.

Im afraid that this iMac, due its 4K resolution, can't handle 3 extra monitors.

What do you say? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Apple documents the supported displays now from the installed OS:

> Check how many displays your Mac supports: Choose Apple () menu > About This Mac > Support, then click Specifications. On the web page that appears, the number of displays your Mac supports appears under Video Support.

I don’t recommend using more than the official, but sometimes people are OK with adapters that split up a display if they don’t care about full resolution or refresh rates as much as maxing out the total square inches of display.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202351

Another option is using an external GPU. See [Use an external graphics processor with your Mac](https://support.apple.com/HT208544) on Apple's website.

From your comments you should expect three 4k displays - up to 2 4K external displays and the iMac integrated one.

Comment: Great link on the eGPU - thunderbolt 3 is USB 4 is fast and hugely extensible for graphical expansion.

Comment: Wow really helpful information, my Mac specs tell that can handle up to 2 4K external display. Im using 2 FULL HD ones so I wonder if there's something I can do to change that.

Comment: 3 distinct 4K displays is a graphic beast. I love the LG 4K displays for text / programming @KarloA.López There are less expensive ones, Dell has some decent ones as well. Go vertical if you can side by side.